# Spring respond only on specified domain

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm developing spring application that run on port 8080. I have IP address `198.51.100.1` and domain `*.example.com`, so my app available on both http://example.com:8080, http://myservice.example.com:8080 and http://198.51.100.1:8080. That is the problem, as port scanner bots can find my service, and because service is doing large work when called and host machine is low-cost VM, even small attack can make service unavailable. So i want to make it answer only when requesting http://myservice.example.com:8080, and myservice.example.com will be known only for certain group of people. Also, domain should be dynamically configurable like `--server.port` option for port or in some file, as service will be deployed on certain number of machines

I know about Apache reverse proxy, but as I said, service deployed on low-cost VM (it's literally potato PC!), and when using reverse proxy, it consumes about 30-50% CPU (other 50-70% goes to my service). I did some benchmarks and it shows that response time is about 1.5 times faster when accessing service directly without reverse proxy

Comment: would wrting a java filter to filter out request comming from other domains work ??
also try to network stack overflow tags here maybe there is a networking solution here that devs wont be able to provide .

Comment: @satyesht any particular examples? how can I filter requests?

Comment: OncePerRequestFilter eg: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter
then in that request :String domain = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost(); to get the domain of the request
and match it with  valid domain names and reject or accept request based on that